# OnPaint Invokes itself when mousing over buttons

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer, onpaint

EDIT: I've tried to solve this for over a week and I have searched here and elsewhere as well.

I'd like to begin with explaining that I am a hobby programmer and have nobody to ask for help. I can only read the books I buy and guides on the internet so I am sorry if the question is beyond stupid.

The case: I have a "Windows Form Application", the form itself is 500x500 in size and in it I have a "Picture Box"(size 400x400, loc 0,0).

I am aware that Thread.Sleep hangs the interface because it is not multi threaded.

The problem I suffer is that "OnPaint" is invoked when I launch the program.
If I add a button (dragged from the toolbox)then "OnPaint" is invoked TWO times and so on, confirmed up to 4 buttons. That is not the worst part however. Just mousing over the button (any button) invokes "OnPaint". As you can see, "Invalidate()" is not inserted yet because I can not even click the buttons yet.

**How do I prevent this? What is the problem? What should I have done differently?
I mean, it does what I want just not when I want to.**

Code:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
            int radie = 25;
            Random random = new Random();
            Graphics graphics = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
            Color color = Color.Black;
            SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(color);

            for (int i = 2500; i > 0; i--)
            {
                color = Color.FromArgb(random.Next(0, 101), random.Next(0, 256), random.Next(0, 256), random.Next(0, 256));
                brush.Color = color;
                graphics.FillEllipse(brush, random.Next(0, 400 - radie * 2), random.Next(0, 400 - radie * 2), radie * 2, radie * 2);
                Thread.Sleep(1);
            }
    }
}
```

For those who wonder what it does it just fills the picture box with circles of different colors and opacity. edit: Its not filled instantly, its supposed to look "pretty".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `OnPaint` event is called any time a control needs to be drawn. So adding things to it, moving them round etc. And as you say, even moving the mouse over it means the control needs to be redrawn.

Comment: If the goal is to set the circles in the picturebox once and not have them change, then do that from the form's Load event.

Comment: @SamAxe The goal is to draw circles continuously, perhaps I misinterpreted how Graphics is supposed to be used? A minor animation is what I had in mind.

Comment: @DavidG I see. That explains a lot. How do I make an OnPaint that is.. seperate?

Comment: Separate from what?

Comment: Feature, not a bug.  The Button control in its default style uses transparency effects.  Hard to see, it is the outer edge for a button that is not the default button of the form, I think.  If you set the FlatStyle to Flat or Popup then it no longer needs it.  But get ahead by making sure that it is not a problem, it certainly never should be.

Answer (score -1):

You could [set the form's ControlStyle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-reduce-graphics-flicker-with-double-buffering-for-forms-and-controls).

In the form .ctor or other appropriate startup event, add:

```
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true);
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
```